# Xcode 13 SwiftUI Color Literal missing

Tags: swiftui, xcode13

I am using the Xcode 13 beta and noticed the `Color Literal` suggestion when trying to choose a color with a picker does not show up (in previous versions I would do `Color(Color Literal())` and a color picker would show up. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `Color Literal` is not showing up for me either after I updated to Xcode 13. Now I have to do `UIColor(named: "name of my color set")` to use my customized color.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70151322/9136962

Answer (score 17):

Just type
`#colorLiteral(` for color or `#imageLiteral(` for image and it will appear immediatly

Comment: This worked for me with the #colorLiteral(  in Xcode 13.  I hope they fix the problem!  Thank you!

Comment: not working, it's just showed "Missing arguments for parameters 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'alpha' in call" :/

Comment: @Stevie, try typing in a empty line #colorLiteral, upon typing ( the square icon for literal will show up.

Comment: this worked on Xcode 14 as well

Comment: It works **on an empty line** (Xcode 14), but that defeats the purpose when you want to add the color as a parameter.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit (September 26, 2021):** As of Xcode 13.0 (13A233), color literals seem to be working now.

---

It's a known issue. From the [release notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20210609010908/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-beta-release-notes):

> #colorLiteral, #imageLiteral, and #fileLiteral aren’t rendered. (75248191)

But other than that, note that [`init(_ color: UIColor)` is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/init(_:)-9rl8m), so you can't do something like `Color(UIColor.blue)`. This applies to color literals too.

Instead, use the new [`init(uiColor: UIColor)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/init(uicolor:)).

Comment: Thank you hadn't seen the release notes

Answer (score 4):

Solved like this in Xcode 13.4:
Put a SPACE after "=" when assigning. Yes, it's that ridiculous. Then double click to pick a color.
So:

`var someColor = #colorLiteral(`

After that can select a color.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, found this answer straight away. I gave up on the colour literal for a long time, but remembered how much easier it was when it was there to use. I wish Apple would have never changed it from colorLiteral, which would autocomplete, to your answer of #colorLiteral( which does not autocomplete. I just have to remember that #colorLiteral( now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#colorLiteral does not work in certain situations.

such as:
bmi = BMI(value: bmiValue, advice: "Eat more pies", color: #colorLiteral()
line above doesn't work.

Comment: came here failing at the same stage

Answer (score 0):

Just type `#colorLiteral(` and then automatically that color swatch is generating. Here you have a clear example:

[image]

My Xcode Version:

[image]

My Swift version:

[image]